# git merge command exits with 1, if it is already up to do date

Tags: git, git-merge

I have this command:

```
git merge "remotes/origin/dev"; echo $?
```

and I get:

```
On branch oleg/feature/1537472700
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/oleg/feature/1537472700'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
1
```

why does it exit with 1? Is the only way to know that everything is ok, is to parse the stdout/stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git merge` exits successfully (i.e., 0) if your branch is up to date.  The message you're seeing, "nothing to commit, working tree clean", comes from `git commit`, which does indeed exit 1 if there's nothing to commit.

It's possible that you have some sort of hook or shell wrapper that's invoking `git commit`, which appears to be the source of your nonzero exit code.

Comment: yeah maybe a pre/post git commit hook?